# as3 How to i solve auto reconnect with settimeout?

Tags: arrays, sockets, actionscript-3

I want to connect my url and port from my vector list. I use setTimeout in my reconnect function but my problem is when i use settimeout and click reconnect button settimout is ask 5 times for connection and when connecttion  succes after connection is down because settimeout is continue send the request my list for connect and states is broken.

How i solve this problem or have any different way ?

```
public static function reconnect(serverUrl:String = "", serverPort:int = 0):void {

            var nextUri: SocketConnection = urisToTry.next;

            test = setTimeout(reconnect, 4000, nextUri.host, nextUri.port);


    }
```

and this is my iteration class

```
public class UriIterator 
{
     public var _availableAddresses: Vector.<SocketConnection> = new Vector.<SocketConnection>();
     public var currentIndex:int = 0;

    public function UriIterator(){

    }


    public function withAddress(host: String, port: int): UriIterator {
        const a: SocketConnection = new SocketConnection(host, port);
        _availableAddresses.push(a);
        return this;
    }


    public function get next():SocketConnection {
        var address = _availableAddresses[currentIndex];
        currentIndex++;
        if (currentIndex > _availableAddresses.length - 1)
            currentIndex = 0;
        return address;
    }




}
```

my list

```
const urisToTry: UriIterator = new UriIterator()
    .withAddress("http://urlone.com", 1211)
    .withAddress("http://urltwo.com", 1212)
    .withAddress("http://urlthree.com", 1213)
    .withAddress("http://urlfour.com", 1214)
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, simplify and clean what you have there.

```
public class UriIterator 
{
    // You won't gain literally anything from using strong-typed Vector.
    // Long variable names make your code harder to read. Use simple ones.
    // Another good idea is to make these members private
    // so no one else will mess with them from the outside. 
    private var list:Aray = new Array;
    private var index:int = 0;

    // If constructor does nothing you might as well omit it.

    // It is not prohibited to do it the way you did,
    // yet again no gain for unnecessary complications.
    public function append(host:String, port:int):void
    {
        list.push(new SocketConnection(host, port));
    }

    public function get next():SocketConnection
    {
        var result:SocketConnection = list[index];
        if (++index >= list.length) index = 0;

        return result;
    }
}
```

Then.

```
private var uriList:UriIterator;

uriList = new UriIterator;
uriList.append("http://urlone.com", 1211);
uriList.append("http://urltwo.com", 1212);
uriList.append("http://urlthree.com", 1213);
uriList.append("http://urlfour.com", 1214);
```

Finally.

```
private var recId:uint;

// Event handler for refused connection or disconnected socket.
private function onDisconnect(e:Event):void
{
    // Dispose of existing/failed connection objects first.
    // @TODO

    // Just in case.
    clearTimeout(recId);

    // Now, lets schedule the next connection in 4 seconds.
    recId = setTimeout(onReconnect, 4000);
}

private function onReconnect():void
{
    // Get the next connection.
    var aNext:SocketConnection = uriList.next;

    // Put your connection routines here.
    // @TODO
}
```

Comment: I update my code with yours but my problem is continue, when i connect automaticly with reconnect function after 1 sec connection down again.

i want, when i click button start reconnect function , reconnect function have settimeout and check my list. When connect ip and port setTimeout is not clear  why ? and my states is every time change because settimeout is try to continue for connection..

Comment: @KaraEski As far as you didn't provided that part of your code that handles connecting and errors, my answer is not a solution, it's a guideline. You are not supposed to "update your code with mine" and expect  it to magically work. You need to work out the logic of your application, to write the flow down as a block diagram (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_diagram), and then to put the logic into code. That's what programming is about.